# Export Folders as MBOX Files Using a Script

Tags: applescript, ms-office

You can manually drag your folders to desktop to create an MBOX file, 
but need to create using  AppleScript.
please help me.

thanks

Comment: did you try using Automator?

Comment: thank for replay,mbox file generate using applescript not use software . how can possible?   Automator provide script?

Comment: you can run scripts in automator, or yous try "watch me do"

Comment: how to generate script? currently not any script with to generate  "Create Mbox file in Office 2011 MAC from Database".

Comment: http://www.office.mvps.org/database/export_mbox.html

Comment: this link already refer but not working

Comment: Do you do any home work your self, like use Google search ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Archive Message Folders by Jolly Roger**
>
> This script archives each folder in your Entourage folder list to a folder on your desktop named "Entourage Archives".
>       The script preserves the hierarchy of the folders, as they exist in the Entourage folders list, by creating sub-folders in the "Entourage Archives" folder that correspond to the sub-folders in Entourage.
>       The exported MBOX files have the same name as the folders in Entourage, with the exception that forward slash characters (/) are replaced with dash characters (-) to avoid problems with the Mac OS X file system.

or

> **Export Folders by Barry Wainwright**
>
> You must create the archive folder yourself before running the script.
>       All folders and subfolders are dumped into one folder. This requires you to have unique names so you can maintain the folder order.

[Source](http://www.office.mvps.org/database/export_mbox.html)

Comment: http://www.office.mvps.org/database/export_mbox.html not working this script ..

Comment: please if any other script then provide

Comment: what is not working ?

Comment: show  Error -2700

Comment: any solution for this error?

Comment: hello sir , find any solution?

Comment: i try to same code in other account then Error :

"miscrosoft outlook got an eroor : can't get every folder." number -1728 from every folder

Comment: code :

tell application "Microsoft Outlook" to set folderList to the foldeer

Comment: The link to the script is sadly dead. If anyone happens to have it, it'd be cool to have it uploaded again. Thanks in advance :)